# Reducing an if statement to generate a mongoid query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, mongoid

I have the code below and I would like to know if it possible to reduce the code.

```
bank_accounts = self.client_bank_account_id.nil? ? self.client.bank_accounts : self.client.bank_accounts.where(_id: self.client_bank_account_id)
```

I only need the `where` call when `client_bank_account_id` is not `nil`.

Comment: (1) Remove `self.` everywhere, it's not required. (2) Remove `.nil?` and swap clauses, non-nil value is considered `true` in Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly shorter, but I'd say its more readable:

```
bank_accounts = self.client.bank_accounts
bank_accounts = bank_accounts.where(_id: self.client_bank_account_id) unless self.client_bank_account_id.nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends, are you going for 'shortest code possible' code golf style or simply the nicest, possibly easier reading code.

I'd go with:

```
bank_accounts = client.bank_accounts
bank_accounts = bank_accounts.where(_id: client_bank_account_id) if client_bank_account_id
```

Notes:

- You don't need 'self'.
- nil checks are probably not the best way to go.
- Lazy loading should stop there being two calls to the db here